# How to do black box testing?

Tags: testing, black-box

Opposed to white-box / API testing, which is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990568/how-to-test-an-api)

There are many interviews, both for developers and qa, where you are asked to test smth out. A classic is to **test the save dialog from notepad**.

Here is a list of tests I can come up with, categorized and prioritized:

[functional, high] - dialog performs its use cases - comes up when the user does a "save as", the buttons on the left work, the file is saved with the given name and encoding, top buttons work, cancel button works.

---

[functional, medium] - save to a Read Only medium - does a fair error pop up?

[functional, medium] - save an empty file

[functional, low] - save a file as .txt but delete the extension from the name

[functional, high] - make sure the dialog is modal

[functional, high] - make sure the dir navigation & dir features work

[functional, high] - context menu options work

---

[load, low] - navigate to a directory where there are a very large (aproaching the system limit) number of .txt files; save the file there

[load, low] - navigate to a directory with a large number of sub-directories. save the file there.

---

[stress, low] - navigate to a directory with a maximum number of files allowed and try to save the file

[stress, low] - saturate the system with file handles (to simulate apps that have very rich interfaces or handle leaks, like Yahoo Messenger); does the dialog pop ?

[stress, medium] - try to save a files when there isn't space on the disk.

[stress, low] - check how deep the "navigate to last folder" button goes with this

[stress, low] - navigate to a directory with a very large number of directories

---

[performance, low] - measure the time needed to display the dialog

[performance, low] - measure the resources used by the dialog (memory, window handles, I/O); make sure the resources are dealocated

---

[accessibility, high] - is the dialog compatible with the accesability tools win provides? (magnifier, narrator); for example that the menu items scale well when choosing large fonts

[accessibility & compatibility, medium] - is the dialog compatible with famous 3rd party programs that provide accessibility features?

---

[localization, high] - the dialog works on other locales

[localization, high] - random inputs of UTF-8 and ANSII letters as the file name

[localization, medium] - right to left locales

---

[compatibility] - make sure that the file saved can be opened by other editing tools, no matter what the encoding is

---

[usability, high] - user is asked if he is sure he wants to overwrite a file

Can you add some more? Or comment on these ones?

Comment: There are good points of comparison with White box testing at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402161/black-box-vs-white-box-testing